# Добрый день! Прошу разъяснить, нужна ли запятая в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В соответствии с поручением вице-президента по науке 
П.Д. Галькина от 03.12.2013 (п.4 протокола оперативного совещания №АР/оп-31) направляю Вам актуализированную справку о статусе реализации проекта ВНХК-30 по состоянию на 28.05.2014.

Answer (score 2):

Предлог "в соответствии с" обособляется факультативно. Основной фактор, влияющий на обособление, - сильная синтаксическая позиция (позиция между словами с сильной синтаксической связью: подлежащим и сказуемым; основной и придаточной частью предложения; однородными членами и т. д., а также не в начале и не в конце предложения):

*Ровно в три часа, **в соответствии с** трудовым законодательством, принес ключи доктор наук Амвросий Амбруазович Выбегалло.*

В вашем примере синтаксическая позиция слабая - в начале предложения, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Подробнее о пунктуации при составных производных предлогах можно почитать здесь: http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/

Answer (score 1):

В письмах делового характера обороты с производными предлогами (в данном случае с предлогом В СООТВЕТСТВИИ), как правило,не обособляются.